# Вызов функции один раз при нажатии клавишы

Tags: java, c#

Есть такой код:

```
    int Switch5 = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.GetKeyState(0xA1);
    if ((Switch5 & 0x8000) != 0)
    {
        act = !act;
        if (act)
        Console.WriteLine("true");
        else Console.WriteLine("false");
    }
```

При нажатии клавиши SHIFT - программа заходит сюда. Но! Если его держать и не отпускать - bool act быстро изменяется с false на true. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии shift act была true, даже в том случае, если его держать постоянно? А при нажатии на shift ещё раз - переменная изменялась на false

Comment: У вас код написан на двух языках сразу? Почему две метки?

Comment: @AK, тут что Java, что C# - в данном коде не имеет значения, ибо разница тут лишь в выводе в консоль

Comment: Имеет значение. Потому что скорее всего не на Java не на с# ваш код повторить не получится, а следовательно ответ вы не получите. Либу нужно подключить через using или import в зависимости от с# или java.

Comment: Вам нужно получить код нажатой клавиши, и поставить блок если предыдущая клавиша равна текущей, или для всех, или конкретно для shift. Там есть где-то события "клавиша нажата", и "клавиша отпущена".

Comment: Приведите программу к такому виду, что бы было видно 1)код (сканкод) нажатой клавиши 2)признак нажата клавиша или отпущена. Тогда на вопрос можно будет ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как насчет самой простой защиты

```
private volatile bool _IAmWorking;
public void KeyEventHandler(EventArgs event)
{
    if (_IAmWorking) return;
    _IAmWorking = true;

    ......

    _IAmWorking = false;
}
```

Для однопоточного варианта, вы можете отследить, когда кнопка была нажата и когда отжата

```
private bool _canRunLogic = true;
public void ShiftKeyDownEventHandler(EventArgs event)
{
    if (!_canRunLogic) return;
    _canRunLogic = false;

    ......    
}


public void ShiftKeyUPEventHandler(EventArgs event)
{   
    _canRunLogic = true;    
}
```

Comment: это поможет если приложение многопоточное, и _IAmWorking - помечен volatitle. В один поток такой ситуации не будет. Я думаю что тут один поток, потому что простой вопрос.

Comment: @nick_n_a думаете, что клавиши будут нажиматься с бешеной скоростью с разных потоков? Речь же просто о нажатии на одну клавишу

Comment: Я хочу сказать что если *клавиши будут нажиматься с бешеной скоростью с разных потоков* то такой блок сработает:) Так же... сработает если будет функция "рекурсивно" по неосторожности вызываться, что тоже очень редкий случай.

Comment: @nick_n_a ок ок, добавил volatile, и второй вариант заодно, пусть автор развлекается.